# Can't download images with arrows while using Html2Canvas JsPlumb. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, jsplumb

In Html2Canvas JsPlumb connectors are not showing. Is there any possible to show connectors.

This is the output in my page. When downloading its not arrows.

[image]

When download arrows are not capturing

[image]

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" >
  <title>JSPlumb Example</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .custom-connection {
      stroke: #1e8151;
      stroke-width: 2;
    }
    .custom-label {
      padding: 2px 5px;
      background-color: #1e8151;
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.9.3/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      jsPlumb.ready(function() {
        jsPlumb.draggable($(".box"));

        var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
          Endpoint: ["Dot", { radius: 5 }],
          Connector: ["Bezier", { curviness: 50 }],
          PaintStyle: { stroke: "#1e8151", strokeWidth: 2 },
          HoverPaintStyle: { stroke: "#1e8151", strokeWidth: 3 },
          ConnectionOverlays: [
            ["Arrow", {
              location: 1,
              id: "arrow",
              length: 10,
              foldback: 0.8
            }],
            ["Label", {
              label: "Connection 1",
              id: "label",
              cssClass: "custom-label"
            }]
          ],
          Container: "canvas"
        });

        instance.connect({
          source: "box1",
          target: "box2"
        });

        instance.connect({
          source: "box2",
          target: "box3"
        });

        instance.connect({
          source: "box3",
          target: "box1"
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function captureAndDownload() {
            console.log('Button clicked');
            html2canvas(document.querySelector("#selecteddate")).then(canvas => {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                link.download = "datatable.png";
                link.click();
            });
        }
                </script>

<body>
    <div id="selecteddate">
        
    <button value="Download" onclick="captureAndDownload()" />
  <div id="canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative;"></div>
  <div id="box1" class="box" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box" style="left: 200px; top: 50px;">Box 2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box" style="left: 200px; top: 200px;">Box 3</div>
</div>
    </body>
    
</apex:page>
```

expecting download images with arrows